# margin decreasing as the window size decreases

Tags: css

I'm trying to create something like yahoo.com where the content is in the middle and on the outskirts there's a grey margin (or at least something looking like a margin, not sure if it's padding). I was successful, however when the page is resized by the user I want this margin to decrease just like it is on yahoo.com but its not decreasing (go to www.yahoo.com and resize the page and their margin decreases). Anyone knows how to get this margin to decrease?

```
 body 
{ 
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans";
    background-color: #525252;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    min-width: 650px;
    min-height: 685px;
    color: #00008B;    
}

table
{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    border-spacing: 0; /* remove the spacing between the borders. */
    width: 950px;
    height: 685px;
    background-color: #C1CDC1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to create a container div of fixed width within your body tag for the content and set the margin to auto.

```
body { 
 text-align: center; 
}
div#container { 
 width: 960px; 
 text-align: left; 
 margin: 0 auto 
}
```

May I also recommend firebug or something alike as a useful tool to inspect, among other this, css and html of websites?

Comment: i also had to put in the body: margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;  not sure why but when I did it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Change your body style to:

```
 body { 
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans";
    background-color: #525252;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width: 650px;
    min-height: 685px;
    color: #00008B;    
}
```